# Replace string eg. "[EMAIL]" with a ASP.net Control

Tags: asp.net, replace, controls

i have this form i need to build, but a user can have it laid out in different ways.

the layout of the form is kept in a xml file and will contain things like

```
<div class="holder">
 <div>name</div>
 <div>[Name]</div>
<div>Surname</div>
 <div>[Surname]</div>
<div>Contact Numer</div>
 <div>[ContactNumber]</div>
<div>Email</div>
 <div>[Email]</div>
<div>[Submit]</div>
</div>
```

What i need to do is replace those [name]etc.. tags with asp.net controls and be able to read the content of those controls. i have hit a brick wall on this, can anybody help me please.

Comment: "replace those [name]etc.. tags with asp.net controls" as in `<asp:Label runat="server" id="lblName" Text="Name />` ?

Comment: Well, that is the answer. If you're using Visual Studio 2010, just add the controls you want from the toolbox..

Comment: No that's not what i want to do, the form gets generated from the xml file. it reads the string from the node and from that string it will replace the [name] with the control so the user will see the control

Comment: Ah! So you want to dynamically create controls at runtime from the code-behind?

Comment: yes, is it possible ? if it is can you show me please

Answer (score 0):

To create a new control at runtime, from code-behind:

**Text Box**

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox
                              {
                                  ID = "dynamicTextBox",
                                  Text = "This is a new textbox"
                              };
        [Container].Controls.Add(textBox);
```

You can do the sae for any other control.

Comment: Hi, this is not working for me. i am trying to do a string replace as in testhtml.Replace("[name]",textbox.Rendercontrol()). but its failing plz help

Comment: Instead of making `<div>[Name]</div>`, I would create `<div runat="server" id="name"></div>`. Then create `foreach (var controls in Form1.Controls)` to search for all the controls. Use an `if` statement to get the controls only pertaining to the name 'name', then use my above method to insert the control; where `name.Controls.Add(textbox);`

Comment: that could help but it has to be dynamic i cant let the agents add in id="someID" i will have to do a replace [name] with control